# Let $G$ be a group and consider $H=\{x\in G\mid|x^G|<\infty\}$. Show to that $H$ is subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and consider $H=\{x\in G\mid|x^G|<\infty\}$. Show
>   to that $H$ is subgroup of $G$

First $e\in H$, because if $e\in x^G$ then $|x^G|=1$ and $e\in G$.
Now I have to show that if I have $a,b\in H$ then multiplied the inverse of $b$ is in $H$.
I have to the inverse of $b$ is in $G$, I have to prove inverse of $b$ also implies that $|x^G|$, but I don't know like show that.

I don't know if exist other way for this prove. Thank you

Comment: Could you define $|xG|$? Out of context I would assume you meant the cardinality of $\{xg\mid g\in G\}$, but that doesn't make sense here.

Comment: xG = {z ∈ G : z ∼ x} = {z ∈ G : z = gxg−1 para cierto g ∈ G} and |xG| is the order

Comment: that would normally be denoted $x^G$ rather than $xG$. I formatted your question with that in mind; let me know if it doesn't accurately represent your question.

Comment: Hint: Show that $(ab^{-1})^G\subseteq(a^G)(b^G)^{-1}$ (where $B^{-1}=\{b^{-1}\mid b\in B\}$ and $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,\,b\in B\}$ for $A,B\subseteq G$).

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $|x^G|=|G:C_G(x)|$, where $C_G(x)=\{g \in G: gx=xg \}$, the centralizer of $x$ in $G$. Now in general, if $H,K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, then $|G : H \cap K| \leq |G:H| \cdot |G:K|$ (finiteness is not necessary here by the way, it could be interpreted as cardinal numbers). Observe that if $a, b \in G$ then $C_G(a) \cap C_G(b) \subseteq C_G(ab)$. This implies that $|G: C_G(ab)| \leq |G:C_G(a) \cap C_G(b)| \leq |G:C_G(a)| \cdot |G:C_G(b)|$. Hence, if $a^G$ and $b^G$ are finite, then $(ab)^G$ is finite.

By the way, the groups with the property that *every* conjugacy class is finite are called $FC$-groups. There is a vast literature on these groups, see for example the books of Derek Robinson *[Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups](http://www.springer.com/fr/book/9783540056201)*: and also [here](http://www.dipmat2.unisa.it/ischiagrouptheory/IGT2010/talks/deGiovanni.pps).